sum of symmetric an antisymmetric bilinear form
If $b_1: X\times X\to \mathbb{F}$ is symmetric and $b_2: X\times X\to \mathbb{F}$ is antisymmetric bilinear form, and nonzero elements $x,y\in X$ are such that $(b_1+b_2)(x,y)=0$, is it necessarily true both $b_1(x,y)=0$ and $b_2(x,y)=0$? No assumption on the dimension of $X$.
I'm trying to see, if nonzero $x,y$ are such $(b_1+b_2)(x,y)=(b_1+b_2)(y,x)=0$, is it true that $b_1+b_2$, when restricted to span{$x,y$} is reflexive? Thanks in advance.

No, and you can find a counterexample with $2 \times 2$ matrices; there's nothing preventing $b_1(x, y) = - b_2(x, y)$. However, your second paragraph uses a stronger hypothesis; we have $(b_1 + b_2)(y, x) = (b_1 - b_2)(x, y)$, so if the characteristic is not $2$ it follows that $b_1(x, y) = b_2(x, y) = 0$.
